# (Batch File) List files in a specific directory but only filenames?

Tags: batch-file

Hi Im quite new to programing and Im trying to make a batch file list music in one of my folders but i only want to see the names. I always get something like this:

> C:\users\sebastian\appdata\roaming\zones\music\song1.mp3

this is what i used

```
for %%a in (%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Zones\Music\*.mp3) do echo %%a
```

is there any way i can get it to just say **song1** or at least **song1.mp3**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the delimiters (`FOR /?`) :

for **song1**

```
for %%a in (%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Zones\Music\*.mp3) do echo %%~na
```

for **song1.mp3**

```
for %%a in (%userprofile%\AppData\Roaming\Zones\Music\*.mp3) do echo %%~nxa
```